# Currency exchange rates through a web service in MATLAB

Tags: web-services, matlab, currency

How can I obtain the current exchange rate for two given currencies in matlab?

I tried [this](http://www.kxcad.net/cae_MATLAB/techdoc/matlab_external/f5978.html) one, however it seems that the web service is no longer available.

Is there another easy way of obtaining the up-to-date currency exchange rates through a web service in matlab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build a local class from a currency conversion web service using [CREATECLASSFROMWSDL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/createclassfromwsdl.html). You can then use the web service's operations to do the conversion using the class methods. One currency conversion web service (there are many) is available at http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?WSDL. Here's an example of its use:

```
>> converter = createClassFromWsdl('http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?WSDL');
Retrieving document at 'http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?WSDL'
>> converter = CurrencyConvertor
    endpoint: 'http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx'
        wsdl: 'http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?WSDL'

>> ConversionRate(converter, 'CAD', 'EUR')

ans =

0.7059

>> ConversionRate(converter, 'USD', 'CAD')

ans =

0.953
```

Note that ConversionRate returns a char array, i.e. you still have to convert the result with str2double if you want to do calculations with the exchange rate.

A list of the currency abbreviations is available at http://www.webservicex.net/ws/wsdetails.aspx?wsid=10.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but thought I would update the answer. I made this currency converter function in MATLAB ([exchangerate.m](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/47255-exchangerate-m)) that utilizes the openexchangerates.org API, which is better supported and also includes historical data. Here's a description how it works (it's very simple):

This function returns exchange rates obtained from openexchangerates.org 
using their API. To work correctly, one must be connected to the 
Internet. The default app_id is from a free account to 
openexchangerates.org, which has a limit of 1000 API requests/month. For 
more flexibility, sign up for your own free or paid account and replace 
the app_id value with your own id number.

**Inputs:**

> 1) **base**: a string denoting the base currency, which is set to have a 
>   value of 1. If an empty string '' is provided, the default 'USD' is
>   used.  See list of valid currency abbreviations below.
>
> 2) **curr**: a
>   string or cell array of strings denoting the currency  abbreviation to
>   compare with the base currency. If 'all' or '' is  provided as input,
>   then all available currencies are returned. See list  of valid
>   currency abbreviations below.
>
> 3) **date**: an optional string containing
>   the date desired for the exchange  rate (historical data may not
>   always be available). The input should be  in the form 'YYYY-MM-DD'.
>   To get the latest exchange rate data, use date 
>   = 'latest' or '', which is the default value. Historical data from 1999  and onward

**Outputs:**

> 1) **rates**: a number or vector indicating the exchange rate(s) between the  desired currency (currencies), curr, and the base currency, base.
>
> 2) **currencies**: a cell array of the corresponding currency
>   abbreviations  in rates.
>
> 3) **rate_struct**: a structure with field names
>   equal to the currency  abbreviations and associated values being the
>   rates. This output just  combines rates and currencies for
>   convenience.

**Examples:**

1) Get the latest exchange rate between Bitcoin and the US Dollar (Note: All country abbreviations are listed in the m-file)

```
[rates,currencies,rates_struct] = exchangerate('USD','BTC'); 
>> rates = 1.614e-3 
>> currencies = 'BTC' 
>> rates_struct = 
       BTC: 1.614e-3
```

2) Get latest exchange rates for all available currencies

```
[rates,currencies,rates_struct] = exchangerate();
```

3) Obtain exchange rates for Bitcoin, Indian rupee, and Euro using the US 
Dollar as base currency on June 5, 2013

```
[rates,currencies,rates_struct] = exchangerate('USD',{'BTC','INR','EUR'},'2013-06-05'); 
>> rates = [8.246e-3; 5.672e1; 7.642e-1] 
>> currencies = {'BTC';'INR';'EUR'} 
>> rates_struct = 
      BTC: 8.246e-3 
      INR: 5.672e1 
      EUR: 7.642e-1
```